# How do I dynamically add widget to grid?

Tags: layout, kivy, widget, addition

I have a Button in the top boxlayout that I want to add a widget to my grid layout below.

Here is my .py file code

```
    class rootWidget(BoxLayout):
        pass
        
    class topWidget(BoxLayout):
        print("top part")
        
    class middelWidget(GridLayout):
        pass
        
    class bottomWidget(BoxLayout):
        pass
    
    class NewButton(Button):
        pass
    
    class mainkv(App):
        
        def newButt(self):
            print("button clicked")
            
            butt = NewButton(text="New Button")
                    
            middelWidget().add_widget(butt)
        
        def build(self):
            return rootWidget() 
      
    mainkv().run()
```

And here is my .kv file

```
    <topWidget>:
        Button:
            text: 'CLick add to grid'
            on_press:
                app.newButt()
    <middelWidget>:
        cols: 6
        id: grid
        Button:
            text: 'middel Grid'
        
            
    <bottomWidget>:
        Button:
            text: 'bottom'  
        
    <rootWidget>:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Root'
        
        topWidget:
        
        middelWidget:
        
        bottomWidget:
```

I am not getting any errors but it's not working.
Can't figure out what am missing any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code:

```
middelWidget().add_widget(butt)
```

is creating a new instance of the `middelWidget`, and adding the `Button` to that new instance. However, that new instance of `middelWidget` is not part of your GUI, so nothing happens. The fix is to use the instance of `middelWidget` that is already in your GUI. That can be done using `ids`. Here is a modified version of your `rootWidget` rule in the `kv`:

```
<rootWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Root'
    
    topWidget:
    
    middelWidget:
        id: middle  # id for accessing middelWidget
    
    bottomWidget:
```

Then the `newButt()` method can be:

```
def newButt(self):
    print("button clicked")

    butt = NewButton(text="New Button")

    middle = self.root.ids.middle  # get a reference to the middelWidget instance
    middle.add_widget(butt)
    # middelWidget().add_widget(butt)
```

Also, your classes should begin with and upper case letters. This is not just for appearance, it can cause errors when those classes are used in `kv`.